# Kubernetes: migrate from flannel to canal or install calico network policy alongside flannel

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I installed flannel as a CNI for my Kubernetes cluster. Now I want to add a network policy to my cluster. After searching I find Canal (Calico for policy and flannel for networking).

How I can migrate from flannel to canal? Or is there any way to install Calico network policy alongside current flannel installation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Canal is just a another name for flannel, so there is no way to migrate, but there is a way to migrate from flannel/Canal to Calico as described [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/flannel/migration-from-flannel).

To install Calico for policy and flannel (aka Canal) for networking, please have a look [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/flannel/flannel#installing-with-the-kubernetes-api-datastore-recommended).

Comment: Hello @nader and welcome to ServerFault! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: Hello @WytrzymałyWiktor and thank you for your advice. I read the link mentioned in the answer but before I install the Canal, I need to remove the flannel. How I can remove it? and what happens to my running pods if I remove the flannel then install Canal?

Comment: To remove Flannel from the cluster usually it's enough to run kubectl delete -f <flannel.yaml> and reboot all nodes to get rid of any interfaces created by Flannel. You may need to rejoin worker nodes to the cluster after that.